Writing to Azure Blob Storage from local spark environment
I've been going round in circles trying to write to a blob storage account in azure. Currently i'm creating a spark session with the following setup:
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Azure Blob Storage Access") \
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1\
    ,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage-blob:11.0.1\
    ,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.4.0\
    ,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1\
    ,org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:11.0.7\
    ,org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty:hadoop-shaded-guava:1.1.1\
    ,org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13\
    ,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1\
    ,com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.1\
    ,org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:11.0.7\
    ,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1\
    ,com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-core:1.2.6\
    ") \
.getOrCreate()

Which results in the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)

I've also tried installing the above jars on the following path
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.1/libexec/jars

But end up with the same error being kicked back. I'm at a bit of a loss where to go with this. I've seen a couple of success stories running this code as either setting the jar parameter within the session config or by having them installed locally. How the hell do i get this working?
UPDATE:
I've confirmed SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME paths in the .env With the jar files locally i've managed to get a different error now.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o307.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON$Convertor

Not sure this is any better but at least its different

How did you set-up the local environment? Is it in Jupyter notebook or in vmware? can you provide any document that you have followed to set-up spark in local environment?

Download hadoop-azure and azure-storage jars from the maven portal manually and copy these jars to spark/jars/. folder.

@RakeshGovindula Currently running this in a Jupyter Notebook running in a pipenv virtual env. I've updated the SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME paths. I've also updated the local jar files with those being passed as the key value pairs above. Now returns the
'''
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o307.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON$Convertor
'''
Despite that jar being in the same path it's not being recognised

Here's how I did it:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("Azure Blob Storage Access")
    .config(
        "spark.jars.packages",
        ",".join(
            [
                "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1",
                "com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6",
            ]
        ),
    )
    .getOrCreate()
)

SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "**secret_account_key**"
STORAGE_NAME = "**storage_account_name**"
file_path = "abfss://**container**@**storage_account_name**.dfs.core.windows.net/"

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
    "fs.azure.account.key." + STORAGE_NAME + ".dfs.core.windows.net", SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

data = [
    ("X", "20-01-2023", "N"),
    ("X", "21-01-2023", "S"),
    ("X", "22-01-2023", "S"),
    ("X", "23-01-2023", "N"),
    ("X", "24-01-2023", "E"),
    ("X", "25-01-2023", "E"),
    ("Y", "20-01-2023", "S"),
    ("Y", "23-01-2023", "S"),
]
# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "date", "state"])

# Write the dataframe to the Azure ADLS location:
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(file_path + "magic.csv")

# Read the data from the Azure ADLS location:
spark.read.format("csv").load(file_path + "magic.csv").show()


Root cause finally identified as Jetty-Util and Jetty-Util-Ajax version being 11 instead of 9. Thanks to the answers above pushing I managed to confirm the azure and hadoop jars were not the issue. Eventually I came across this link about Jetty Util having deprecated classes in Jetty Util Version 10+. I dropped down to Jetty-Util and Jetty-Util-Ajax v9.4.45 from Maven, updated my JDK to Open-JDK 16 and successfully wrote to the Azure Storage Account.
